# Is there a way to use JSONAPI with other multipart/form-data?

Tags: .net-core

I am using JSONAPI (jsonapi.org) in my .NET core project (JsonApiDotNetCore). I need to prepare controller to accept a file. Is there a way to use JSONAPI with multipart/form-data as well, or is there another way how to do it in controller derived from JsonApiController? I am asking this because in documentation it says that the content type for requests is application/vnd.api+json and when I try with multipart/form-data I don't get any data.